# Python and matplotlib - simple chart not showing, no errors

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is about as simple can get with matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
print 'done'
```

When I run, I get no errors, no charts, and goes straight to printing 'done'.

I installed on ubuntu 10.04 using easy_install.

Comment: How are you running the code? In a script or in an interpreter?

Comment: The code actually displays a plot for me either way.

Comment: I am Running in eclipse.

Comment: Well you could try running the code in the python interpreter, or directly as a script. If that doesn't work, you'll know there's something wrong with your installation.

Comment: tried that...same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your backend is probably a non-interactive backend (such as 'Agg'). Have you got the backend setup in your matplotlibrc file?

Try:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # or some other backend which you have installed

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
print 'done'
```

You can find the location of your matplotlib rc file with:

```
import matplotlib
import os

print os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(), 'matplotlibrc')
```

You should be looking for something like `backend: Agg`.

Comment: I get this error.      import _tkagg
ImportError: No module named _tkagg

Comment: Maybe you don't have a TkInter installation. Do you have any other GUI toolkits available? Gtk, Qt4, WxPython etc.?

Comment: yup..sudo apt-get install python-tk

Comment: If you've just added Tk then it might be worth re-installing/building matplotlib so that it can build the appropriate C library.

Comment: Just did that...no go.  Even when so far as to reboot.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you running?
How are you installing matplotlib?

Comment: I assume that you can do `import Tkinter` from the python session from where you are running matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

The backends are probably not installed; try installing the Ubuntu package `python-matplotlib`. If you're in ipython, try running the cell `%matplotlib inline`.